# How do I return a column value based on whether another column is within an array range - Libreoffice Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, spreadsheet

If I have a comparison array like so on sheet "A"...

| Size | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SM | 0 | 99 |
| MD | 100 | 199 |
| LG | 200 | 999 |

...and on sheet "B" I Have...

| Val | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | ?? |
| 250 | ?? |
| 150 | ?? |
| ... | ... |

How can I compare the value in the "Val" column on Sheet "B" with the Min/Max columns on Sheet "A", and return the "Size" column value from Sheet "A" (i.e. SM, LG, MD in the examples) as the result?

I've been working with **VLOOKUP** but I just can't get it to work and most answers I've found are dealing with text comparisons, not values within an array range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VLOOKUP will not work as the lookup column is right of the return column.  Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A!A:A,MATCH(A1,A!B:B))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks Scott!